# Storing value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pointers

I'm working with a dictionary that will store data for a library called `calendar`. The library will have a format as follow

```
{day : [log_book, [borrow_info], [return_info], [add_book], [fine]]}
```

and

```
log_book = [[book_name], [quantity], [restricted_type]]
```

I intended to have each day storing a unique value into `log_book`. I attempted to do it by making this function

```
def update_storage(calendar, day, log_book):

    data = calendar.get(day)
    data[0] = log_book
    calendar.update({day:data})

    return calendar
```

However, as far as I understand, this creates a pointer instead of a unique value for each day.
This is the result I wanted

```
{0 : [[['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 1], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']], [], [], [], []],
 1 : [[['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 0], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']], [['1', 'adam', 'harry potter', '6']], [], [], []], 
 2 : [[['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 0], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']], [], [], [], []],
 3 : [[['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 0], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']], [], [], [], []]}
```

This is the result that I currently get even though I did not update day 1 (key = 0) at all

```
{0 : [[['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 0], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']], [], [], [], []],
 1 : [[['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 0], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']], [['1', 'adam', 'harry potter', '6']], [], [], []]}
 2 : [[['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 0], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']], [], [], [], []], 
 3 : [[['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 0], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']], [], [], [], []]}
```

As you can see on day 2 (key = 1), adam borrowed a book named `"harry potter"` which decrease the quantity of the book down from 1 to 0. However, when I updated the dictionary, it changes every value to the current `book_availability` . This is an example how I updated the value using the function mentioned above

```
book_availability = [['Introduction to python', 'harry potter'], [3, 0], ['TRUE', 'FALSE']]
calendar = update_storage(calendar, day, book_availability)
```

What did I do wrong? I'm new to data structure and pointers.

Comment: The description seems unclear.  Please provide a test data, your current result, and what you intend to have.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for pointing it out. I have just edited the post with more information.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that you don't actually have separate copy of "quantity" (and maybe ("restricted type") for each "day"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if something like this work in your expected / desired way:

```
def update_storage(calendar, day, log_book):

    data = calendar.get(day)
    data[0] = log_book.copy()
    data[0][1] = data[0][1].copy()
    calendar.update({day:data})

    return calendar
```

I don't know how is your whole program like, but it seems that you are manipulating the same (set of) list(s) (of "literals").

This makes `data[0]` points to `book_availability` (which consists of "pointers" to a bunch of lists) when it's passed as `log_book`:

```
data[0] = log_book
```

which means each `day` shares the same `log_book`.

This will give each `day` a separate `log_book`:

```
data[0] = log_book.copy()
```

**BUT**, since `.copy()` does only a *shallow* copy, which means each pointer in the copy will still be pointing to the same thing (list).

Therefore, to allow each day to have its own record of "quantities", you will at least need:

```
data[0] = log_book.copy()
data[0][1] = data[0][1].copy()
```

Note that `data[0][1] = data[0][1].copy()` alone is not sufficient either, because if it were used with `data[0] = log_book`, you would be making one same `log_book` shared by all the `day`s point to a new copy of "quantity" (that had / will have the "literals" in it updated).

P.S. What I wrote serves only as an explanation to your doubt. It's probably a bad way to achieve your goal in reality.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It helps a lot. I really appreciate it!